# Fonts Rendering Improperly in JComboBox

Tags: java, fonts, jcombobox

I'm trying to make a JComboBox that displays all of the available fonts in Java, and have the names of those fonts display in their respective fonts. The list seems to work for the most part, but quite a few of the fonts either render as giant blank spaces, or with all of the letters stacked on top of each other:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIbCh.png]

Is it a problem in my code, or is it the OS/Java (Windows 8, JDK 1.7.0_55)?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.*;

public class TextEditor extends JFrame{

    private static JPanel j;
    private static String[] fontNames =     GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    public TextEditor(){
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(j);
        setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        setTitle("Text Editor");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        initComponents("Sampe Text");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextEditor edit = new TextEditor();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void initComponents(String s){
        j = new JPanel();
        j.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JComboBox<String> fonts = new JComboBox<String>(fontNames);
        fonts.setRenderer(new ListRenderer());
        fonts.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                final String font = fonts.getSelectedItem().toString();
                fonts.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, 16));
            }
        });
        fonts.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        j.add(fonts, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private static class ListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            String selectedIndex = (String) value;
            setFont(new Font(selectedIndex, Font.PLAIN, 16));
            setText(selectedIndex);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a couple that display as a black rectangle but none that overtype. I'm using JDK7 on Windows 7. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so other can test the code on different versions/platforms to see if they still have the same problem.

Comment: Added SSCCE. Weird that it renders differently for you, maybe it does have something to do with the OS?

Comment: Post the code in the forum.

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: In addition to my original comment, I should also mention I don't get any blank lines, so could be a platform difference.

Comment: Weird, I thought that could be part of the problem but it seemed like kind of a stretch. It seems strange that if it is dependent, it's between two versions of Windows rather than something like Windows and OSX.